# Where could I find a pdf of Tate's Thesis?

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-number-theory

my professor asked me to read about Tate's Thesis, but I have looked everywhere and I couldn't find the thesis itself. I found lecture notes and introductions on the the thesis. I am confused. Is Tate's Thesis a thesis? If so, where would I be able to find it?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: See [Chapter 15](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~cais/scans/Cassels-Frohlich-Algebraic_Number_Theory.pdf). It first appeared in print as Chapter XV of the conference proceedings Algebraic Number Theory, edited by Cassels and Frolich (Thompson Book Company, Washington, DC, 1967).

Comment: I really do not understand the downvotes and the closing request on this post. Does any-downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @CalvinLin I appreciate your help!

Comment: Tate's thesis at Princeton was certainly a thesis: see https://catalog.princeton.edu/catalog/9917763463506421.  But you should read it as a chapter in the book Calvin Lin mentioned or see other books that go over it: chapters in Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory*, Goldstein's *Analytic Number Theory*, or Ramakrishna and Valenza's *Fourier Analysis on Number Fields*.